# can't crawl page with simple scrapy spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am very new to scrapy and I am trying to scrape a website using simple spider (built on the basis of another spider found here: http://scraping.pro/web-scraping-python-scrapy-blog-series/ ).

Why does my spider crawl 0 pages (there are no errors):

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from items import NewsItem

class TutsPlus(CrawlSpider):
    name = "tutsplus"
    allowed_domains = ["net.tutsplus.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://code.tutsplus.com/posts?page="
    ]

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/posts?page=\d+']), 'parse_story')]

    def parse_story(self, response):
        story = NewsItem()  
        story['url'] = response.url
        story['title']     = response.xpath("//li[@class='posts__post']/a/text()").extract()        
        return story
```

and very similar spider running well:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from items import NewsItem

class BbcSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "bbcnews"
    allowed_domains = ["bbc.co.uk"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology/",
    ]

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/technology-\d+']), 'parse_story')]

    def parse_story(self, response):
        story = NewsItem()
        story['url'] = response.url
        story['headline'] = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()
        story['intro'] = response.css('story-body__introduction::text').extract()
        return story
```

Comment: I think your `allowed_domains` doesn't allow even starting page

Comment: @furas,  No, this is not it. I changed     allowed_domains     to: allowed_domains = ["code.tutsplus.com"] , still 0 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your regex `'/posts?page=\d+'` is not what you really want, as  this matches urls like: `'/postspage=2'` and `'/postpage=2'`.

I think you want something like `'/posts\?page=\d+'`, which escapes the `?`.

Comment: It almost works as expected (unfortunately "almost"). Spider crawls only 4 pages: http://code.tutsplus.com/posts?page=2, http://code.tutsplus.com/posts?page=3, http://code.tutsplus.com/posts?page=465, http://code.tutsplus.com/posts?page=466. Any idea why only those pages?

Comment: because those are the only ones available that match that regex? check the site.

Comment: all are available from 1 to 466 (http://code.tutsplus.com/posts?page=1, http://code.tutsplus.com/posts?page=2 and so on)

Comment: pages were avaliable but there was another issue (beyond specified by @eLRuLL). I added **follow = True** to rule (**rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = ['/posts\?page=\d+']), callback='parse_items', follow = True)]**. Now everything is working properly. @eLRuLL, thank you very much for your help!